# Computing the logarithmic residue of $\sin(z)/z$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Compute the logarithmic residue of the function $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ at all poles and zeros.

I know by a proposition that $\text{res}_{z=z_k}\frac{d\ln(f(z))}{dz}$ is equal to the sum of the order of each zero minus the order of each pole. $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=0\implies z=k\pi\:,\:k\in\mathbb{N}$.

However I have no idea on how to compute the order of zero $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$.

**Questions:**

Is it right what I have done insofar? How should I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give a reference to the mentioned proposition? What is $z_k$?

Answer (score 1):

To compute the order of the zero of $\sin(z)/z$ at $\pi$, look at the Taylor series for $\sin(z)$ around $\pi$ (because $1/z$ has no zero or pole at $\pi$);
\begin{align}
\sin(z)=-\sin(z-\pi)&=-\left[(z-\pi)-\frac{1}{3!}(z-\pi)^3+\dots\right]\\
&=-(z-\pi)\left[1-\frac{1}{3!}(z-\pi)^2+\dots\right],
\end{align}
and read the order of the zero at $\pi$ to be 1.

Comment: But the number of zeros would be infinite because $k\pi,\:k\in\mathbb{N}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @PedroGomes I would assume that you are missing the correct formulation of the proposition mentioned in your question.